# Use of homogeneous coordinates to intersect lines

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Here we are in $P(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Let the two lines $x=1$ and $x=-1$ lives in the related affine space.

How to intersect these two lines in the projective space ?

I'm a bit confused about homogeneous coordinates and how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ket $X,Y,T$ the homogeneous coordinates in $P(\mathbf R^2)$. The equations of the projective lines are $X=T$ and $X=-T$. They intersect at a point such that $\: X=T=-T$,  which implies $T=X=0$, so that the intersection point is
$$(X:Y:T)=(0:1:0)$$
i.e. the point at infinity of the $Y$-axis.

Comment: So fundamentally knowing the equivalence relation of colinearity can we say that $( 0 : \lambda : 0 ), \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ is also an intersection point ?

Comment: It is the  same point in the projective plane  if $\lambda\ne 0$. Projective coordinates are defined up to a nonzero constant factor.